# Finding the Derivative without using Product or Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a math problem where I am required to find the derivative of a function with the limitations of ***not being allowed to use*** the Product or Quotient Rule of Differentiation.

The problem looks like this:

$$h(x) = \frac{4-x^6}{3x^{-2}}$$

I have tried a variety of routes but always end up with results that seem to require the use of the Product or Quotient Rule.

For example, my latest try looks like this:

$$h(x) = \frac{4-x^6}{3x^{-2}}$$

$$h(x) = \frac{4}{3x^{-2}} - \frac{x^6}{3x^{-2}}$$

$$h(x) = \frac{4x^2}{3} - \frac{x^8}{3}$$

(From this step, I figured I could just use the Difference Rule of Differentiation, like this:)

$$h'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{4x^2}{3}\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^8}{3}\right)$$

But wouldn't this actually end up using the Product -or- Quotient Rule?  Like this:

$$h'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{4}{3}(x^2)\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{3}(x^8)\right)$$

Is there another route I can take with this type of problem that would avoid using the Product or Quotient Rule of Differentiation?

Comment: "Product Rule" generally refers to finding the derivative of the product of two non-constant functions. I believe the approach you took is the one intended by whomever wrote the question.

Comment: You could alternately find the derivative *from the definition of derivative*. To save headaches, it is useful to make a preliminary simplification to $\frac{4}{3}x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^8$. You probably did the derivative of $x^2$ from the definition in class, the argument for the $\frac{4}{3}x^2$ part will be essentially the same. And the argument for the $\frac{1}{3}x^8$ part is not too bad, just expand $(x+h)^8$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261705/945479

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are allowed to use the [Constant Multiple Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_multiple_rule), i.e. $(cf(x))'=c(f(x))'$, where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: This looks like what the instructor intended; thank you for the direction!  I can't believe I overlooked this rule...

Answer (score 4):

Let $$h(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$$

So, $$\ln h(x)=\ln f(x)+\ln g(x)$$

Differentiating wrt $x$ using [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),

$$\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

$$\implies h'(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)+\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}\cdot f'(x)=g(x)\cdot f'(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)$$

If $f(x)=c,$ (constant)

$f'(x)=0$ and $h(x)=c\cdot g(x)\implies h'(x)=c\cdot g'(x)$

Comment: Eventually you are back to *product rule* .

Comment: @Inceptio That's what I was thinking... :/  I was intrigued about the use of `ln()`, though...

Comment: Nice to mention logarithmic differentiation, a very useful idea.

Comment: @Inceptio, put $f(x)=4-x^6, g(x)=\frac{x^2}3$ from the start

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I wish I could accept both answers on this question... but for the time being (and I'm sorry for not clarifying this in the original question,) I might accept the *"Constant Multiple Rule"* response because I haven't yet reached the *Chain Rule* in my particular class at school (although I know this is going to be a way to solve many things, in the future.)  Thank you so much for your time and your response, though!

Comment: @summea, sharing ideas & clearing confusions is much important than the acceptance of a solution. Btw, I've derived the constant multiplication formula, if you notice till last.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but doesn't this derivation of the product rule only work if $f$ and $g$ are strictly positive functions?