# proving the quotient rule for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to show the Quotient Rule for derivatives by using just the Product rule and Chain rule. I dont have a clue how to do that. Maybe someone provide me with information.  THX

Comment: Don't even need chain rule: we can use this often useful trick $$f(x) = \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)  \cdot g(x) $$

Comment: @Hurkyl The full statement of the product rule says: If both factors are differentiable then the product is differentiable and can be expressed as yada-yada. The differentiability of the quotient may not be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $$f(x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)} = g(x) \cdot (h(x))^{-1}$$ i.e., invert the denominator of a quotient of functions, after which you can use the product rule. And the chain rule applies, as usual. $$f'(x) = g'(x)[h(x)]^{-1} + g(x)\Big(-[h(x)]^{-2}\cdot h'(x)\Big)$$

Now, simplify (finding common denominator), and you'll have $$f'(x) = \dfrac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better answer to this question is the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Sitnik-Bourbaki}\tag{1}
\frac{\textrm{d}^k}{\textrm{d}z^k}\biggl(\frac{u}{v}\biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^k}{v^{k+1}}
\begin{vmatrix}
u & v & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
u' & v' & v & \dotsm & 0\\
u'' & v'' & 2v' & \dotsm & 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots & \dotsm\\
u^{(k-1)} & v^{(k-1)} & \binom{k-1}1v^{(k-2)} &  \dots & v\\
u^{(k)} & v^{(k)} & \binom{k}1v^{(k-1)} & \dots & \binom{k}{k-1}v'
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $u=u(z)$ and $v=v(z)\ne0$ are differentiable functions.
For more information on the formula \eqref{Sitnik-Bourbaki}, please refer to another answer of mine at the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261705/945479.