# Can someone help with this question please? (derivatives)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In this question, you will prove the quotient rule for derivatives using the product and chain rules.

Let $h$ and $g$ be differentiable functions, with $g(x) > 0$ for all $x$, and let $f(x)=x^{-1}$.

First, calculate the derivative, $f'(x)$. Then, note that the quotient $\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$ can be written as the composite, $h(x)[(f \circ g)(x)] = h(x)f(g(x)).$

Then, use the product and chain rules to derive $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{h}{g} = \frac{h'g - hg'}{g^2}$.

Comment: This is poorly phrased:
"In this question, you will prove the ...."
Why do you assume anyone will prove this for you?

Comment: haha sorry that was just how my tutor phrased is in the assignment and I copy and pasted it on here. Didn't mean to sound rude. I would hope the polite way I phrased my intial question is proof enough for that.

Comment: NP.  Welcome to S.E. Mathematics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261705/945479

Answer (score 1):

Hint(s):
$$
f'(x) = -x^{-2}
$$
You have using the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{h(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} h(x)f(g(x)) = h'(x)f(g(x)) + h(x)\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))
$$
Now you just have to apply the chain rule and the simplify.