# Flawed proof of the quotient rule for differentiation

Tags: calculus

In his *Cameos for Calculus* (page 12) Roger B. Nelsen gives the following "proof" of the quotient rule as an application of the product rule:
$$
w=\frac{u}{v}\implies u=vw
$$
then
$$
u'=(vw)'=v'w+vw'
$$
therefore solving for $w'$ yields
$$
w'=\frac{u'v-v'u}{v^{2}}.
$$
and then he mentions that

> "But there is a serious flaw in this "proof." What is it?"

The proof looks fine to me and I'm curious to know what Prof. Nelson might have had in mind as a serious flaw in this argument. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261705/945479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof assumes that we already know that the quotient $w=\frac{u}{v}$ is differentiable, while part of the point of the quotient rule is to actually prove this fact.

Comment: This might have been the point of the author, but I wouldn't call it a serious flaw because I can interpret the rule differently (or in a weaker form): If $w=u/v$ is the quotient of two differentiable functions then $w'=\frac{u'v-vu'}{v^2}$ at any point of differentiability of $w$.

Comment: @Simon: You are right, but then we have a problem in using the Rule, since in principle we cannot know that the answer we get is correct, since the point of interest might not be a point of differentiability.