# Finding the nth derivative in the form $d(a/b)/dx$, given the values of the $n$th derivatives of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would you go about analytically finding the nth derivative in the form:

$$\frac{d^{n}\left(\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\right)}{dx^{n}}$$

given that we know the equations for

$\frac{d^na}{dx^n}$ and $\frac{d^nb}{dx^n}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Edit: To give some context, I am working on some python code that should calculate
$$\frac{d^{n}\left(\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\right)}{dx^{n}}$$

I have an array of values for $a$ and for $b$.
I am able to calculate arrays of values for $\frac{d^na}{dx^n}$ and for $\frac{d^nb}{dx^n}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/whats-the-generalisation-of-the-quotient-rule-for-higher-derivatives