# Formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ Derivative of the Reciprocal of a Polynomial

Tags: derivatives, induction

Is there a formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of the reciprocal of a polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{K} a_k x^k$?

**Question 1:** In particular, does there exist a formula for
$$g_n(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{K} a_k x^k}\right)$$

In my particular case a partial fraction decomposition cannot be found for the denominator. If anyone knows of the answer to the first question, I am also curious about an equation of the following form.

**Question 2:** Does there also exist a formula (in terms of $n$) for the following derivative?
$$\hat{g}_n(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{x}{\sum_{k=0}^{K} a_k x^k}\right)$$

Comment: Try defining $g(x)=1/f(x)$ where $f(g)g(x)=1$ and then use Leibniz rule for $n$-th derivative of the equation to get a recursion for $n$-th derivative of $g(x)$.

Comment: Related: [What'st he generalisation of the quotient rule for higher derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/whats-the-generalisation-of-the-quotient-rule-for-higher-derivatives) In your cases, take $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$, respectively.